# Blur text or face in Google Photos

Tags: google-apps

I want to blur parts of my Google photos. Editing the original so that all albums that the photo is already a part of are automatically updated.

I found this [locked thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/photos/CTf7_otNWCQ) saying it is possible on the phone using SnapSeed. I did the [blur as described in a video](https://youtu.be/nawItfbEI0Q) I found. The blur looked great. However, SnapSeed does not replace the original, instead it creates a new image with the same timestamp as the original. Which isn't too terrible, just want to know if there's a better app.

I was hoping to do this in the Google Photos website on my desktop browser in a way similar to how you can with YouTube videos, no luck however.